# docker redis: Failed opening Unix socket: bind: Address in use

Tags: docker, redis

I am trying to create a Docker container for `redis`. I want other services to connect to this container using a Unix socket instead of a TCP/IP socket.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
services:
  redis:
    command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/usr/local/etc/redis
      - /var/run/redis.sock:/var/run/redis.sock
```

In the `redis.conf` file I have enabled the Unix socket:

```
unixsocket /var/run/redis.sock
unixsocketperm 700
```

When I try to start the container, I get this error:

> Failed opening Unix socket: bind: Address in use

I do not have any Redis instance already running on my machine.

I have seen some solutions which use a second container to hold the Unix socket and then share it using docker volumes, like [this one](https://medium.com/@jonbaldie/how-to-connect-to-redis-with-unix-sockets-in-docker-9e94e01b7acd):

```yaml
services:
    tmp:
        image: busybox
        command: chmod -R 777 /tmp/docker
        volumes:
            - /tmp/docker/    
    redis:
        image: redis
        command: redis-server /etc/redis.conf
        volumes:
            - /redis/redis.conf:/etc/redis.conf
        volumes_from:
            - tmp
```

I have not tried this solution, but anyway I would like to avoid this additional container and simply expose the Unix socket on the Docker host.